# Frequency data differences test across two groups

Tags: statistical-significance, frequency

I am looking into contrasting two groups with regards to frequency differences over a few time points.

To make it clearer:
I have for group 1, the frequency difference 5; 4; 1; 2; 3
and for group 2: 3; -3; -1; -2; 2

The negative differences are crucially important as it essentially shows the 'typical' effect is reversed by a certain magnitude.

If I use a simple chi-squared test for this it will however treat my negative differences of let's say -3 just as my positive difference of 3, which is not really capturing the scale.

So, I am a little unclear as to what statistical test I could perform here.

Comment: what's a frequency ratio?

Comment: Here I mean for example: I count in category 1/apples: 5 observations and in category2/pears: 7 observations. Then I would always take the apples:pears ratio as my measure. In this example: 5-7 = -2. The order of how I create this ratio is crucial.

Comment: 5-7 is a *difference*, not a *ratio*.

Comment: Okay, I am happy to call it rather a frequency difference then, any ideas how I could test these difference values?

Comment: Do you have the original counts from before the differences were taken? One problem - of several here - is that counts generally don't have constant variance, but a variance which is related to the mean (e.g. consider binomial or Poisson or negative binomial distributions... or even just the fact that counts are necessarily non-negative). This will then impact the variances of the differences.

Comment: I do have the original counts, yes. Because of the issues with variance that you are mentioning I was hoping to run an alternative to a variance test. How would permutation tests deal with such situation? Would that be an option?

Comment: I believe you could do a permutation test/randomization test(/some kind of bootstrap test), but if you have the original counts you should also be able to fit a GLM that has the test you want to perform as a significance test of a coefficient in a GLM.

Comment: Meaning forming a differences variable and take the differences score for each participant? That is theoretically a good idea, but I have too few counts per individual to actually do that. If that is what you mean.

Comment: I didn't actually mean that, no. If the difference is of prime importance, for a GLM, you could perhaps put the first one in as an offset though (if you had an identity link), and have the second as a response. I've never tried that though; I assume it would work.

Comment: I like that idea. I am however not entirely sure what you mean. How would I assign an identity link to my first values?

Comment: If you have a subset of your data (two columns of counts for group1 and group2) I could try to set it up to show you. Actually, it should be possible to do it as a form of chi-square as well.

Comment: Okay, here it is: group 1: column 1: 0,0,1,1,1(sum = 3); column 2: 0,1,1,0,0 (sum = 2); group 2: column 1: 0,0,0,0,1 (sum = 1); column 2: 1,1,0,0,1 (sum = 3). I always have to take the difference of column 2 - column 1. And you see the issue for group 1 if I would want to bring that into a typical chi-square test: difference= -1 (group 1) vs difference= 2 (group 2). Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: We have a gap between your original data and this data. Let's take the summing as a given  (sum = 3, sum = 2) and so on. You have a lot more data than that! Why do you say you *have* to take the difference? What will happen to you if you hold off taking the difference until we see the sums that you took differences of?

Comment: Thanks for you comment, Glen. Yes this is just a subset of my data. In any case, I am afraid I don't understand your question: 'What will happen to you if you hold off taking the difference until we see the sums that you took differences of?' I believe that is actually what I am doing. 'Why do you say you have to take the difference?'- because I need this difference to be evaluated between the two groups not the individual columns.

Comment: I understand that you want to test for a change, but that may not be best achieved by taking the difference directly. See how you have 5 sets of differences, for two groups giving ten numbers? What would it look like if you gave the numbers you differenced to get those, so there were 5 pairs for group 1 and 5 pairs for group 2? Those *20* numbers may be more useful.  Are these pairs before-and-after values?

Comment: Dear Glen. I ended up using a McNemar test (uncorrected). I am quite happy with this. Thank you for helping me through this.